# Prisma create empty model object

Tags: javascript, model, prisma

How can I create an empty model object in prisma without typing every atribute?

I I have the following model:

```
model Compra {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  anoMes      String
  fecha       DateTime
  ccf         String
  neto        Decimal   @default(0)
  iva         Decimal   @default(0)
  excento     Decimal   @default(0)
  total       Decimal   @default(0)
  proveedor   Proveedor @relation(fields: [proveedorId], references: [id])
  proveedorId Int
}
```

I want to create something like this:

```
let empty = {
    id: 0,
    createdAt: '',
    anoMes: '',
    fecha: '',
    ccf: '',
    neto: '',
    excento: '',
    iva: '',
    total: ''
    proveedor: { id: 0, nombre: '', registo: '' },
    proveedorId: 0,
};
```

Is there a shorthand o do I have to create one for every model I have?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I am not aware of any shorthand. You need to create a custom function for every model.

But if your goal is dealing with typescript related types you can use type assertion. Here's an idea:

```
import { Compra } from "@prisma/client";

const emptyCompra = {} as Compra
```

Note that this won't initialize any properties.

Comment: I wish if I could upvote more ...

Answer (score 0):

Every property in the model of a Prisma schema **must** have a type.

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-fields

Declaring the type is part of declaring the field - you must have both. A field can be nullable (if not an array type you can add a `?` to the end of it), and you can use types native to the kind of database you're using (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#native-types-mapping), but there's no way to completely omit a field's type.

When Prisma interacts with your underlying database, it NEEDS to know the type of data it's working with when constructing tables/columns/queries. The types are also crucial to the emitted TypeScript client, which provides super helpful type-hinting when performing CRUD operations.

Comment: What I want is an empty object (a variable) that has all the fields in the model. The model is properly defined with all of its types.